# How to fix a 403 server error on a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, learnpress

I am facing a 403 error on my WordPress site ([https://interactiveit.lk/](https://stackoverflow.com)).

This is a LMS website where I have used Learnpress to enable the LMS feature. The theme is eLearningWP from Thimpress. I have removed all the other themes as well

However the problem is that the website is working fine until a visitor clicks on a lesson under the curriculum and then the 403 error appears which breaks the whole site.

[Here is the list of lessons under the curriculum tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WChB4.png)

[The 403 error appears as soon as a lesson is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVwPN.png)

I have made sure that only the logged in and enrolled users can view the curriculum, lessons and so on in detail but even a logged in and enrolled user faces the same issue.

I am not sure what is the problem here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

FYI, I have listed all the plugins in use:

- Black Studio TinyMCE Widget
- Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce
- Click to Chat
- Contact Form 7
- Elearningwp Demo Data
- eRoom - Zoom Meetings & Webinars
- Html5 Video Player
- LearnPress
- LearnPress - Students List
- LearnPress - WooCommerce Payment Methods Integration
- Page Builder by SiteOrigin
- Paid Memberships Pro
- Paid Memberships Pro - WooCommerce Add On
- SiteOrigin CSS
- SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle
- Thim Core
- Ultimate Member
- WooCommerce
- WP Coder
- WPCode Lite

I have tried all the common ways of fixing the 403 error like fixing the htaccess file, deactivating and reactivating the plugins, changing file permissions but still the problem persists.

Comment: There is no way we can answer this for you. Are you sure your rules for viewing protected courses are correct?

Comment: As far as I know, I have set it correctly as per the instructions from the developers. To make sure, I reset the settings and re-installed too